# How To Get the Array Value from AsyncTask to other Method in Android Studio

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, for-loop

Hi guys Now I have an asyncTask method. Inside, I have create an Array and do for loop to filter data. So my question is, how can I get the latest Array value to my other method?

Comment: Some code blocks would be helpful!

Comment: hi @Desmond, welcome to stackoverflow. before we are able to help you, perhaps you could provide us with [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i know to handle AsyncTask you can user interface, 
Create an interface with a callback method:

```
public interface callBackListener {

    void Responce(ArrayList data);
}
```

in the Activity where you want to have array list :

call you asyncTask Method with this parameters and asyncTaskMethod parameter should be Type of ( callBackListener callback) :

```
asyncTaskMethod(your_parameters, new callBackListener (){
      @Override
       public void Responce(ArrayList bundle) {

       }
});
```

and in your asyncTaskMethod when you hanve updated array then call:

```
callback.Response(arrayList);
```